Objects in Jenkins that can be used in template of emailext
According to the Email Extension and the example template html and text, I found the objects:

build: object of type AbstractBuild
project: object of type AbstractProject

Another objects be used in example but I don't know the type of it:

it

it.timestampString

Be used in other question

listener

build.getEnvironment(listener)

Is listener also a default object from Jenkins?
Is there have a complete list that show all the objects can be used in template?
Thanks
